# Vagrant multi-vm ssh not working

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a multi vm environment set up by using the Vagrantfile at the bottom. But I can't ssh into any of the boxes. I have tried 
vagrant ssh vm-cluster-node1 
but it says "The machine with the name 'vm-cluster-node1' was not found configured for this Vagrant environment."

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

$master_script = <<SCRIPT
#!/bin/bash
cat > /etc/hosts <<EOF
127.0.0.1       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

10.211.55.100   vm-cluster-node1
10.211.55.101   vm-cluster-node2
10.211.55.102   vm-cluster-node3
10.211.55.103   vm-cluster-node4
10.211.55.104   vm-cluster-node5
10.211.55.105   vm-cluster-client
EOF

apt-get install curl -y
REPOCM=${REPOCM:-cm4}
CM_REPO_HOST=${CM_REPO_HOST:-archive.cloudera.com}
CM_MAJOR_VERSION=$(echo $REPOCM | sed -e 's/cm\\([0-9]\\).*/\\1/')
CM_VERSION=$(echo $REPOCM | sed -e 's/cm\\([0-9][0-9]*\\)/\\1/')
OS_CODENAME=$(lsb_release -sc)
OS_DISTID=$(lsb_release -si | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
if [ $CM_MAJOR_VERSION -ge 4 ]; then
  cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudera-$REPOCM.list <<EOF
deb [arch=amd64] http://$CM_REPO_HOST/cm$CM_MAJOR_VERSION/$OS_DISTID/$OS_CODENAME/amd64/cm $OS_CODENAME-$REPOCM contrib
deb-src http://$CM_REPO_HOST/cm$CM_MAJOR_VERSION/$OS_DISTID/$OS_CODENAME/amd64/cm $OS_CODENAME-$REPOCM contrib
EOF
curl -s http://$CM_REPO_HOST/cm$CM_MAJOR_VERSION/$OS_DISTID/$OS_CODENAME/amd64/cm/archive.key > key
apt-key add key
rm key
fi
apt-get update
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -q -y --force-yes install oracle-j2sdk1.6 cloudera-manager-server-db cloudera-manager-server cloudera-manager-daemons
service cloudera-scm-server-db initdb
service cloudera-scm-server-db start
service cloudera-scm-server start
SCRIPT

$slave_script = <<SCRIPT
cat > /etc/hosts <<EOF
127.0.0.1       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

10.211.55.100   vm-cluster-node1
10.211.55.101   vm-cluster-node2
10.211.55.102   vm-cluster-node3
10.211.55.103   vm-cluster-node4
10.211.55.104   vm-cluster-node5
10.211.55.105   vm-cluster-client
EOF
SCRIPT

$client_script = <<SCRIPT
cat > /etc/hosts <<EOF
127.0.0.1       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

10.211.55.100   vm-cluster-node1
10.211.55.101   vm-cluster-node2
10.211.55.102   vm-cluster-node3
10.211.55.103   vm-cluster-node4
10.211.55.104   vm-cluster-node5
10.211.55.105   vm-cluster-client
EOF
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define :master do |master|
    master.vm.box = "precise64"
    master.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
      v.vmx["memsize"]  = "4096"
    end
    master.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.name = "vm-cluster-node1"
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096"]
    end
    master.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.211.55.100"
    master.vm.hostname = "vm-cluster-node1"
    master.vm.provision :shell, :inline => $master_script
  end

  config.vm.define :slave1 do |slave1|
    slave1.vm.box = "precise64"
    slave1.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
      v.vmx["memsize"]  = "5120"
    end
    slave1.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.name = "vm-cluster-node2"
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "5120"]
    end
    slave1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.211.55.101"
    slave1.vm.hostname = "vm-cluster-node2"
    slave1.vm.provision :shell, :inline => $slave_script
  end

  config.vm.define :slave2 do |slave2|
    slave2.vm.box = "precise64"
    slave2.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
      v.vmx["memsize"]  = "5120"
    end
    slave2.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.name = "vm-cluster-node3"
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "5120"]
    end
    slave2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.211.55.102"
    slave2.vm.hostname = "vm-cluster-node3"
    slave2.vm.provision :shell, :inline => $slave_script
  end

  config.vm.define :slave3 do |slave3|
    slave3.vm.box = "precise64"
    slave3.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
      v.vmx["memsize"]  = "5120"
    end
    slave3.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.name = "vm-cluster-node4"
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "5120"]
    end
    slave3.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.211.55.103"
    slave3.vm.hostname = "vm-cluster-node4"
    slave3.vm.provision :shell, :inline => $slave_script
  end

  config.vm.define :slave4 do |slave4|
    slave4.vm.box = "precise64"
    slave4.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
      v.vmx["memsize"]  = "5120"
    end
    slave4.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.name = "vm-cluster-node5"
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "5120"]
    end
    slave4.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.211.55.104"
    slave4.vm.hostname = "vm-cluster-node5"
    slave4.vm.provision :shell, :inline => $slave_script
  end

  config.vm.define :client do |client|
    client.vm.box = "precise64"
    client.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
      v.vmx["memsize"]  = "4096"
    end
    client.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.name = "vm-cluster-client"
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096"]
    end
    client.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.211.55.105"
    client.vm.hostname = "vm-cluster-client"
    client.vm.provision :shell, :inline => $client_script
  end

end
```

Comment: the Vagrantfile comes from here: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/04/how-to-use-vagrant-to-set-up-a-virtual-hadoop-cluster/

Comment: if you run `vagrant status`, what you get?

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Vagrant status gave me a list of current machine names and I was able to ssh to one correctly. If you add that as answer to question, I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line such as `config.vm.define :slave1 do |slave1|` define the vagrant instance name, in this case it will be `slave1`

So you need ssh to the instance by `vagrant ssh slave1`.

But there is no instance named `vm-cluster-node1`

To help you find out the instance name easily, run this command

```
vagrant status
```